# Proxy Jetty to Apache

Tags: apache-2.2, proxy, jetty

I have a site that is served by jetty on port 8080 and apache is on 80 redirecting requests to jetty. My problem is when ever I shutdown jetty for maintenance or restart and during the period any one tries to access to site, they get proxy not reachable error as expected but even after jetty is back up and serving connections they still keep getting proxy not reachable error until I restart apache. Can anyone tell me why this is happening or is this normal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is due to the `retry` value having a default of 60 seconds. From the [mod_proxy documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html):

> `retry` Connection pool worker retry timeout in seconds. If the connection pool worker to the backend server is in the error state, Apache will not forward any requests to that server until the timeout expires. This enables to shut down the backend server for maintenance, and bring it back online later. A value of 0 means always retry workers in an error state with no timeout.

I was able to get Apache to immediately notice jetty's presence again by setting `retry=0`, like:

```
ProxyPass /jetty/ http://localhost:8080 retry=0
```